# Issue with pinescript strategy

Tags: pine-script

can anyone help with this?
I want a strategy that executes when a candle closes above the 10EMA.
I have the code but the issue I keep getting is:

Compilation error. Line 8: no viable alternative at character '{'

Here is the code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

// Declare variables
var ema = ema(close, 10)

// Check if the current candle closes above the EMA
if (close[1] < ema[1] and close > ema) {
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, leverage=10, size=strategy.calculate_position_size(percent=1, currency=currency.BTC), comment="Short")
}

// Plot the EMA
plot(ema, color=pink)
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

From what I can see the curly braces are correctly referenced and no issue with syntax, so I'm at a wall

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is chatGPT generated code.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the curly braces?
Directly from the reference guide:

```
//@version=5
strategy("if")
if (ta.crossover(high, low))
    strategy.entry("BBandLE", strategy.long, stop=low, oca_name="BollingerBands", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="BBandLE")
else
    strategy.cancel(id="BBandLE")
```

Comment: Thanks Ray, that didn't work unfortunately though. It says: Compilation error. Line 5: Could not find function or function reference 'ema'

Comment: var ema = ema(close, 10)
Variable name is same as function name. Is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

I know that in V5, you need the ta. namespace when referencing built in indicators like the line where you assign the ema variable. It should look like this instead:

```
var ema = **ta.**ema(close, 10)
```

Also as far as I know, the `{}` aren't available to use in an if block, so removing them should resolve the no viable alternative at character '{' error.